# can gsub and %>% work together

Tags: r, gsub

wondering can we use pipe get gsub together? seems I can not

```
t <- c("(66.8309216,20.3991966)","(65.3337311,16.5161694)","(63.4276473,17.7292444)","(63.1711922,14.9591800)",
"(61.3011993,16.1534214)","(61.0917012,14.6663653)")
t%>%gsub('\\(','',t) %>%gsub('\\)','',t)
```

seems not work.also if there is a df and have a column called t, same data inside

```
df$t%>%gsub('\\(','',df$t) %>%gsub('\\)','',df$t)
```

still not work. 
Anyone gives a suggestion?

This works

```
t<-gsub('\\(','',t)
t<-gsub('\\)','',t)
```

Comment: Or use dots instead of `df$t`: `t%>%gsub('\\(','',.) %>%gsub('\\)','',.)`

Comment: I don't do chaining. But I believe you want to use . instead of t to tell it where to put the input from the previous link. So gsub("m","", .) for example. I could be misremembering how these things work though.

Comment: Alternatively use stringr which has the input as the first parameter and the pattern second.

Comment: David / Dason you should write as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work when you adding `{}`, also for pipe call second `gsub` should using `.` instead of `t`

```
t %>%{gsub('\\(','',t)} %>%{gsub('\\)','',.)}
[1] "66.8309216,20.3991966" "65.3337311,16.5161694" "63.4276473,17.7292444" "63.1711922,14.9591800" "61.3011993,16.1534214" "61.0917012,14.6663653"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could replace both expressions in one go:

```
gsub("(\\(|\\))", "", t);
#[1] "66.8309216,20.3991966" "65.3337311,16.5161694" "63.4276473,17.7292444"
#[4] "63.1711922,14.9591800" "61.3011993,16.1534214" "61.0917012,14.6663653"
```

Explanation: Regular expression patterns of the form `(a|b)` match `a` or `b`.

---

Assuming you want to extract entries in the next step, you could then use `read.csv` to automatically populate a `data.frame` with entries from `t`:

```
read.csv(text = gsub("(\\(|\\))", "", t), header = F);
#        V1       V2
#1 66.83092 20.39920
#2 65.33373 16.51617
#3 63.42765 17.72924
#4 63.17119 14.95918
#5 61.30120 16.15342
#6 61.09170 14.66637
```

Answer (score 1):

We can place the brackets inside the square brackets of `gsub` to remove both

```
gsub("[()]", "", t)
#[1] "66.8309216,20.3991966" "65.3337311,16.5161694" "63.4276473,17.7292444"
#[4] "63.1711922,14.9591800" "61.3011993,16.1534214" "61.0917012,14.6663653"
```

---

If the brackets are the start and end characters, then a `substr` method can be used as well

```
substr(t, 2, nchar(t)-1)
```